# AMD bios RAID not detected in Fedora 38

Tags: linux, raid, fedora

I have set up a (pseudo) RAID drive using the BIOS RAID configuration.

I'm using BIOS based RAID because the target drive is shared between a Windows and Linux dual boot configuration and I can't mount an LVM or Windows Spanned disk in the other OS.

After installing the AMD RAID drivers in Windows the drive shows up as expected however it's not visible in GParted when booting into Fedora 38.

`lspci` shows the raid controller as visible but I am not sure how to mount the created drive

```
$ lspci -nn | grep RAID
02:00.1 RAID bus controller [0104]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43bd] (rev 01)
```

and

```
$ lspci -v
02:00.1 RAID bus controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43bd (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1062
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at fce80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at fce00000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 0):

With high probability this is fake RAID controller. It is software based and as you saw it start working only with drivers. Which drivers are available only for Windows OS.

You can try to install Windows drivers in Linux but will be better to manage things in natural way work under Linux with JBOD.